# Why are objects not allowed as keys in associative arrays?

Tags: php, hashmap, associative-array

The [PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) states:

> Arrays and **objects can not be used as keys**. Doing so will result in a warning: Illegal offset type.

AFAIK, PHP arrays are ordered hash-maps. So, why is it per se forbidden to use objects as keys, is there a reason for this limitation? Why is there no possibility to implement a hash function in a class in order to use it as a key?

On a related note, is there a PHP implementation of a hash-map which solves this issue?

Comment: Related: [SplObjectStorage](http://php.net/class.splobjectstorage), available in 5.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keys need to be immutable in order for them to work.  If your objects are mutable, then they can't be keys.  That's true in every language that implements them: Java, C#, etc.

Comment: Question (I'm no expert, just curious): If objects have a memory address (I guess), this memory address doesn't change (I guess?) - if such memory address doesn't change, why is such address not used as a key for this?

Comment: @Omega, Interesting. Some languages may indeed do something like this. However, this would require an intermediate translation mapping between the *runtime* name and the memory address. Furthermore, it would have implications for languages with built in memory management.

Comment: @duffymo I understand keys have to be immutable, but should it not be in the programmer's responsibility to use only immutable fields of a class to generate the hash? (as is e.g. in Java)

Comment: @JasonMcCreary hit the nail on the head at the end. What if your hash is defined in a wider scope than an object within? What happens when your object within falls out of scope and is garbage collected? You now no longer have a way of getting at that key, unless you happened to store the previous memory address. But wait, what if a new object was written at that same memory address? Uhoh.

Comment: @rob Everything is mutable in a PHP object. Always. Even private/protected properties are mutable outside of the scope of the object using reflection. This would make any kind of integrity very difficult.

Comment: @duffymo I'm not sure I agree with: "That's true in every language that implements them". Certainly in Java and (iirc) python map keys are mutable.

Comment: Not in Python.  You can add a mutable key to a Map in Java, but you'll regret it quickly.

Comment: @duffymo You can make sure the hash stays the same in Java by using only the immutable fields of a class to generate it. But I admit it is dangerous if you don't know what you do... and therefore maybe a good thing it is not part of the standard array implementation in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

See @duffymo for the answer.

Note that there is a "*workaround*" of sorts, by using `spl_object_hash` as your key. This returns a string, which is immutable, that can be used as a key and will be the same for any object which occupies that memory address. (Read: `spl_object_hash` will return the same value for the same instance regardless of where it's called or if the object has changed)

Comment: Unfortunately `spl_object_hash` returns a different value on every script invocation, even if the objects are identical.  This would make it kind of inconvenient.

Comment: Well, by definition they are not identical. They are different objects. You'd need to implement your own `equals` method, or something similar. Better question: why do you need cross-invocation comparison in a hash map? Why not find a way to create unique identifiers for these objects and persist them in a system that is meant for this?